# Comparing large values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

So I've stumbled upon this problem:

> Compare the numbers:
>
> $$9^{8^{8^9}} \text{ and }\,8^{9^{9^8}}$$

I got this in a test and I had no idea what the answer to the problem is... Can someone give me the answer and how you can find it? It's obviously not possible to calculate such huge numbers, so there's probably another way to find it which I haven't figured out.

Comment: Are you allowed a calculator for this? If so, it may be possible to use logarithms.

Comment: Well we obviously weren't allowed to use calculators but I'm just looking for an answer now to see if I got it correct, so sure.

Comment: the first has $10^{1.2\times 10^8}$ digits the second only $10^{4.1\times 10^7}$. Notice that *Mathematica* did not the computation directly, because of the overflow. I had to give it in log form. These numbers are unthinkably large. I have no idea how to compare them in another way

Comment: @Raffaele So, which one seems larger?

Comment: The one with more digits, I think...

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe...

Answer (score 5):

$8^9 > 9^8$

In fact it is more than $3$ times greater.

Which would suggest that
$8^{8^9} \gg 9^{9^8}$ ($\gg$ means significantly greater)

So then the next level

$9^{8^{8^9}}$ is a larger base to a larger exponent than $8^{9^{9^8}}$

Answer (score 1):

On my conclusion, $$ 9^{8^{8^9}} > 8^{9^{9^8}} $$

To explain this,

Manually we know, $$ 9\ln(8) > 8\ln(9) $$

therefore, $$ 8^9 > 9^8 $$
$$ 8^9 \approx 3(9^8) $$

now $\ln(9)=2.19$

$\ln(8)=2.07$

i.e. $ \frac{\ln(9)}{\ln(8)}=1.05 $,

therefore $$ 8^9\ln(8) > 9^8\ln(9)$$

$$ 8^{8^9} > 9^{9^8} $$

now, $$ 8^{8^9}\ln(9) > 9^{9^8}\ln(8) $$

concluding,

$$ 9^{8^{8^9}} > 8^{9^{9^8}} $$